# Syntax error in Colab, using the exclamatory mark (!)

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory

To remove all the files except for two:

`!rm -rf !("file1"|"file2")`

But this gave error:

`/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

What syntax should be used as an alternative?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: My bad, still new to this

Answer (score 0):

Try using the colab magic commands (%%bash) to convert the code running in the cell to a bash. Then Try running the same without initial exclamation mark, as you normally do in a terminal